# python how to disable multiple imported module logging

Tags: python, paramiko, pyftpdlib

i have imported 2 modules paramiko and pyftpdlib in my python code.

i am able to suppress paramiko SSH logging to console by using the following line.

```
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

i then tried to disable console outputs from pyftpdlib by placing this line in my function code for starting my ftp server for pyftpdlib

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
```

when i do this it caused paramiko log suppression to stop working and see info messages printed to console from paramiko.

i'm trying to figure how to disable BOTH from logging to console?

Comment: You need to call `basicConfig` _before_ fine-tuning individual loggers.

Comment: Why not to have a try `logging.getLogger("pyftpdlib").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` just like `logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

Answer (score 0):

i figured it, i had to, import config_logging form pyftpdlib

```
import logging
from pyftpdlib.log import config_logging
config_logging(level=logging.ERROR)
```